# Inheriting user controls that use the visual layer in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, user-controls, winui-3

I'm developing an application on WinUI 3. I've created a user control that mainly uses the visual layer. Here is its XAML code.

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.Elements.Dialog"
             x:Name="_Dialog"
             SizeChanged="_Dialog_SizeChanged">
    <Grid x:Name="_MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.35*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.65*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle x:Name="_BackgroundRectangle" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="_CharacterTextBlock" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" MaxLines="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="_PhraseTextBlock" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Justify" MaxLines="4" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I will not attach the code behind it, since it is very large, but I will describe its essence. This code uses the visual layer and completely changes the display of _BackgroundRectangle. Adds a custom DropShadow, applies a GaussianBlurEffect to simulate glass, applies a color, a custom stroke, and a light source to it. And all this using the Visual layer. This code also changes the display of text blocks, adding various effects to it.

My problem is that now I have to create another custom control, which will have half the code exactly the same as the created element. Namely, this will be the BackgroundRectangle. The new element should display exactly the same, but the text blocks will no longer be there. Instead, there will be other content. I could simply copy the duplicate code into a new control, but this is clearly not the best solution, because later I will need to create many more similar controls, each of them will have the same BackgroundRectangle.

I believe that I should split the finished control into two classes. In the first, describe the basic functionality that will be available to all its descendants, which includes defining the BackgroundRectangle and setting the display. And the second class will be responsible for the content that will be located against this background. But I don’t know how to do all this. After all, as far as I know, it is impossible to inherit from XAML, and the base class must have markup in any case. And descendants should complement this markup. Perhaps there would be fewer problems if I did not use the Visual layer, but I simply need it. Please tell me how I can solve my problem?

Comment: You need to define a class, which includes the BackgroundRectangle and some of the same elements. And then when you create the user controls, you could call the method which in this class. However, the XAML for each control needs to be written by yourself.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT, That's what I ended up doing, thanks for the advice!